# Is it possible to host a Windows share that can be accessed solely by server name? (e.g. \\server\file.txt)

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing, share

*DISCLAIMER: I'm simply looking for convenience here. I know that this isn't a big improvement but it's a nice to have.*

There are a number of really useful tools that we host on a file share that folks access all the time. I'm wondering if we can cutdown on some typing time by shortening the path to that share as much as possible.

Right now, it's something like: \\servername\tools\hammer.exe

I'd like it to look more like:  \\servername\hammer.exe

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows file shares must *always* contain at the very least a server name and a folder name, i.e. `\\server\share`; then, inside a shared folder, you can have your file, such as `filename.exe`. Thus, the shortest network path you can create can't be any shorter than `\\server\share\filename.exe`.

You can shorten this on the client side by mapping a drive letter to a network path, as had always been done since Windows NT times; if f.e. you map `N:` to `\\server\share`, then you can refer to `\\server\share\filename.exe` as `N:\filename.exe`.

Drive letter mappings can be controlled via Group Policies and/or logon scripts (a simple `net use` command), so you can centrally manage them for all your users.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Thank you, this is good to know. I was suspecting it was impossible to have \\server\filename.exe but thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK not possible with a SMB share, but if you wanted to host a webdav share windows can access it using **only** the hostname.

As an example look at like `\\live.sysinternals.com` (also https://live.sysinternals.com/).

So internally you might be able to do something similar if combined this with a DNS suffix you should be able to access the webdav share simply by the short version of the name.

Comment: This is a really cool idea. My goal was to be able to have the shortest possible URL, so I may have to buy a short domain and give this a shot :)

Answer (score -1):

How many machines do you have in your workplace? Were the operating systems installed one by one or did you image them/push an OS to them via a network?

If these are imaged machines and can receive their operating systems via a multicast, it may be useful to create your own operating system image with a shortcut to the folder on the taskbar or on the side panel of the Windows file explorer.

-

Elija

*CompTia A+ Certified*

Comment: Pushing a whole new OS image to drop a shortcut onto someone's computer is like demolishing your house every time the dishes get dirty. This is an incredibly inefficient solution to the problem, even assuming that a explorer shortcut would work an the OP isn't working in the shell.